# kendo combobox with custom filter on custom template

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

Is anybody having solution on this issue please try to help me

I have a kendo combo box with custom template having UserID and EmployeeFullName colums, I would like to search on both columns so autocomplete will search for UserID as well as name. I kept text field as Name and Value field as UserID, but filter:'contains' will search only on Name not On Id, please try to help how to achieve this, I tried custom filetr in filtering funtion like below

```
    $scope.CMComboOptions = {
        dataTextField: "EmployeeFullName",
        dataValueField: "UserId",

        filter: "contains",
     filtering:
           function(e){
               var selectedValue = $('#combocontactmanager').closest("span").children("span").children("input").val(); // comboBox.value();

                           if (selectedValue.length > 0) {
                               var filter = new Array();
                               if (!isNaN(selectedValue)) {
                                   var temp = selectedValue.toString().toLowerCase();
                                   filter.push({ field: "UserId", operator: "contains", value: temp });
                               } else {
                                   filter.push({ field: "EmployeeFullName", operator: "contains", value: selectedValue });
                               }
                               dorDataSource.filter(filter);
                           } else {
                               dorDataSource.filter([]);
                          }
               //},
           },


        dataSource: dorDataSource,
        clearButton: false,
        change: function (e) {
              debugger;

            var widget = e.sender;

            if (widget.value() && widget.select() === -1) {
                // console.log(widget.value())
                //custom has been selected
               // widget.value(""); //reset widget
                jQuery("#combocontactmanager").data("kendoComboBox").value("")
                $scope.cMVal = "";


            } 
        },
        headerTemplate: '<div class="dropdown-header">' +
'<span class="k-widget k-header">Id</span>' +
'<span class="k-widget k-header">Employee Name</span>' +
'</div>',
        template: '<span class="k-state-default">#: UserId#</span>' +
'<span class="k-state-default">#: EmployeeFullName#</span>',
    }
```

but its not worked for me,

Comment: What do you mean with "not working for me"?

Comment: Auto complete search result showing only for EmployeeFullName not on UserID, If search any key value its showing Nodata found